# Google playStore Action required PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, privacy-policy

My Android app is live on play store. As per new permission policy, I removed 
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission from my app's manifest and uploaded new apk.

- But still, I am getting an email from Google related to remove "PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" permission from the app.
- Is Anyone know what further steps I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have stopped your old APK completely from being live. Are you sure it is removed from all releases on all tracks (including alpha or beta?)

Comment: Thanks Nick! - >  Yes!, Old apk is present in beta track. There is no provision to remove that app.  Do I need to upload new app with the new version number in beta? or anything else I can do?

Comment: To remove the beta channel entirely it is a bit confusing but can be done. You essentially create a new release, then add no APKs to it (ie make it an empty release) then publish that release to the beta channel.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I will try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Play Developer Support:**

Please noted that the reminder message is aimed at the entire app. APKs which was published to other tracks, including Closed alpha track and Open Beta track, should also exclude relevant permissions.